# Getting eth_ipoib in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, infiniband

I've just discovered an ethernet driver called eth_ipoib which I'd like to experiment with.

However, there appears to be no kernel module for it in the mainline.
http://lwn.net/Articles/507258/

How do I get this going under Ubuntu server?  I haven't been able to even find the source files for it.

Comment: Looks like you can find the patches [here](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netdev/list/?state=*&q=net%2Feipoib&archive=both)  There is discussion also [here](http://marc.info/?l=linux-netdev&w=2&r=1&s=eipoib&q=b)

Comment: Anyway from what I can see in [this message.](http://marc.info/?l=linux-netdev&m=134799917123828&w=2)  `Nobody has given any generic networking review to this patch yet, ... And you can clearly see your patch sitting there in "Under Review" state.` - So if you want to test it you almost certainly are going to have to build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for finding the source.  I'll have to merge it with my kernel and try it out.